# mysql merge specific rows

Tags: mysql, merge, rows

Current Table:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id  ║ price ║ tax ║ sku  ║ description ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 123 ║ 10    ║ 1   ║ sku1 ║ Dress       ║
║ 123 ║ 0     ║ 0   ║ sku1 ║ Dress-Small ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Result that I want:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id  ║ price  ║ tax ║ sku  ║ description    ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 123 ║ 10     ║ 1   ║ sku1 ║ Dress-Small    ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I want to get *id*, *price*, *tax* and *sku* from the 1st row and then get the *description* from 2nd row. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Interesting database design? Maybe that is your issue

Comment: It is a almost same with Magento2 sales table.

Comment: Rows are not guaranteed to be displayed in any order.  You're referencing first and second rows.  What distinguishes those rows?  Did you mean the dress and dress-small rows?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
    SELECT MAX(id) id,
           MAX(price) price,
           MAX(tax) tax,
           sku1,
           MAX(description) description
      FROM Table
     GROUP BY sku1
```

You didn't explain how you know the second row contains the correct description, so this is a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer.  Example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59aa9/14/0)

```
SELECT A.id, A.price, A.tax, A.sku, B.Description
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE description = 'Dress'
) AS A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM MyTable 
  WHERE description = 'Dress-Small'
) AS B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

I would consider taking a hard look at what the `id` column does for your table.  Might as well remove it.